# Ubuntu 12.10 slow start of applications

Tags: 12.10

Some applications on Ubuntu 12.10 starts very slow. I mean the time between click on app icon and first show on screen.

For example VLC player takes at least 15 seconds.

Is there any way how to speed it up?

Comment: Do you still have this problem? 15sec is very long indeed, VLC is not that big. (Here opens in 2 sec) 15 sec timings would indicate network time-outs mostly. Do you see also slow opening behavior on websites?

Answer (score 3):

To make program loading faster, install the `preload` program, which preloads programs using an algorithm to guess which program you're using next. It may sound bad but it's actually quite efficient.

Install it through the `sudo apt-get install preload` in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Use a preloader. I do not see the difference.
Slow loading, applications from the start until the window to 15 seconds.

Do not you see it start or not. Previously, the mouse pointer changes to the watch, now you see nothing.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are totally right.