# Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit Slow

Tags: performance

I am new to linux and was wondering why launching applications is so slow. I've tried both Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit

Computer Specs:
Toshiba Satellite p755
CPU: Intel core i7-2670QM @2.20GHz
Ram: 8 GB
Using integrated intel hd 3000 graphics

When I install the first thing I do is update, which takes about an hour or so. I would assume I'd be good after that, but when launching things like the firefox, system settings, thunderbird it takes a much much longer time than on Windows 7. Please help me.

Comment: What does system monitor say? screenshot?

Comment: Slow... but HOT! http://askubuntu.com/questions/225631/ouch-laptop-running-super-hot-after-12-10-upgrade

Comment: Maybe it is the problem of unity desktop. I've tries unity in ubuntu 12.04, but it is too slow that I change to xfce which is a lightweight desktop environment and has the classic look as gnome2.

Comment: Could be unity but he's talking about applications being slow to start. And most computers are faster with unity and ubuntu than windows 7 in my experience.

Perhaps you have a disk problem? Try looking at the smart data in disk utility to see if your hard disk is ok

Comment: A common suggestion is to install preload: http://askubuntu.com/questions/218546/ubuntu-12-10-slow-start-of-applications. You have more than enough memory to do that.

Comment: Unity may slow the desktop down. You colud try something like lxde. Or maybe XFCE?. Try changing the  desktop enivronment and check if your graphic card drivers  are supporting OPENGL!

Answer (score 1):

End of life for 
Ubuntu 12.10 is May 16, 2014.
Ubuntu 12.04 is April 2017.

However Ubuntu 14.04 is already out and is most updates one. Hence, please use that to be at the better side.

Now, for the performance issue; go to Software Center and type "LXDE" and install the first option. You may use this command in terminal as well: *sudo apt-get install lxde*

LXDE is Lubuntu!! Consider it another name for the same thing. This will make you able to choose between "Unity" (which is the default desktop you know about) and LXDE which is awesome and lightweight.

You can also use "XFCE" as same way as "LXDE" from software center or type in the following command in terminal: *sudo apt-get install xfce4*

XFCE is Xubuntu. It is lighter than regular Ubuntu but heavier than LXDE.
And yes, in both cases, you have to restart your computer.

Hope that helps !!

Answer (score 0):

### Try Ubuntu 12.04/13.10 **32 bit**

At first this may seem weird, but the truth is that 32 bit OS works very well on 64 bit systems.You can download 32 bit OS from [here](Http://www.ubuntu.com).

### Try Lubuntu/Xubuntu

If the first option does not work,
You can use **Xubuntu** or **Lubuntu**(again I suggest you to use 32 bit OS)

Get Xubuntu from [here](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/).
Get Lubuntu from [here](http://lubuntu.net/).

For more info read [can-a-32-bit-os-run-in-a-64-bit-processor?](https://superuser.com/q/9083)